# Transition between multiple divs via dropdown list control

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a very basic page of dashboards, controlled by a dropdown control. The idea being that visitors can select an appropriate dashboard from the dropdown and the corresponding div appears below it. There could be an arbitrary number of dashboards (currently, I have 5; I expect to grow this to 9 or possibly more)

```
<div class="selectview">
    <label for="view-select" style="margin: 2px; font-size:15px; font-family: Bahnschrift; font-weight: bolder; color: #2F75B5;">Dashboard View :</label>
    <select name="views" id="view-select" style="margin: 10px; font-size:15px; font-family: Bahnschrift; font-weight: bolder; background-color: #2F75B5; color: white; height: 30px;">
        <option selected value="1">Dashboard #1</option>
        <option value="2">Dashboard #2</option>
        <option value="3">Dashboard #3</option>
        <option value="4">Dashboard #4</option>
        <option value="5">Dashboard #5</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="dashboard1" id="dashboard1"></div>
<div class="dashboard2" id="dashboard2"></div>
<div class="dashboard3" id="dashboard3"></div>
<div class="dashboard4" id="dashboard4"></div>
<div class="dashboard5" id="dashboard5"></div>
```

The dashboards are actually separate HTML files, loaded as part of $(document).ready. To switch between the dashboards, I just detect the change in the dropdown and switch the display from 'block' to 'none' or vice versa as appropriate.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(function(){
        $("#dashboard1").load("../Dashboard1.htm"); 
    });
    
    $(function(){
        $("#dashboard2").load("../Dashboard2.htm"); 
    });
    
    $(function(){
        $("#dashboard3").load("../Dashboard3.htm"); 
    });

    $(function(){
        $("#dashboard4").load("../Dashboard4.htm"); 
    });

    $(function(){
        $("#dashboard5").load("../Dashboard5.htm"); 
    });

    $('#view-select').on('change', function () {
        $("#dashboard1").css('display', (this.value == '1') ? 'block' : 'none');
        $("#dashboard2").css('display', (this.value == '2') ? 'block' : 'none');
        $("#dashboard3").css('display', (this.value == '3') ? 'block' : 'none');
        $("#dashboard4").css('display', (this.value == '4') ? 'block' : 'none');
        $("#dashboard5").css('display', (this.value == '5') ? 'block' : 'none');
    });

    $("#dashboard1").css('display', 'block');
    $("#dashboard2").css('display', 'none');
    $("#dashboard3").css('display', 'none');
    $("#dashboard4").css('display', 'none');
    $("#dashboard5").css('display', 'none');
}
);
```

This works fine but I want to "snazz" it up a bit by having some form of animated transition between the div's when the user changes the value in the dropdown. Nothing too dramatic or complex, even if was a simple fade-out / fade-in or maybe a slide-out / slide-in - to be honest, I don't know the possibilities available. I just want something that looks slightly more sophisticated than a sudden switch between the div's.

I've tried researching css transitions and animations but I can't figure out how to implement them (I half suspect using the css display class is what's holding me back but I don't know any other method of switching the visibility of a div)

Thanks in advance for any tips, suggestions or pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `dashboard` class to dashboard `div` elements than you van apply this `js` code

```
$('#view-select').on('change', function () {
    var daheboards = document.getElementsByClassName("dashboard");
    for (let index = 0; index < daheboards.length; index++) {
        daheboards[index].style.display = "none";
    }
    $("#dashboard" + this.value).fadeIn();
});
$("#dashboard1").fadeIn();
```

You can also set the action time to `fadeIn()` function in `ms` to control fade in time `fadeIn(1000)` or `fadeIn('slow')` [jQuery fadeIn() doc](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/)